# How to write to specific offset in empty file

Tags: c, linux, file

I have a file in which I read in data.  Suppose the file has the string "abcdefghij".  Now, I'm going to be reading from the file at random times from different processes and they store that byte and offset somewhere.  For instance, I save 'c' as my character with an offset of '3' because that is its location.  For reference, I've been using lseek to get the offset in my files.

Next, I want to write this to a new file.  Is it possible to write to a specific offset in an empty file?  So, I want to write 'c' to position '3' in the file and then another process will write 'j' to the file at position 10.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about an offset in an empty file. You would have to add some filler chars.

Comment: Is this absolutely required?  Because if my source file contains 100 or even 1000 characters.  It may take a while to write to the 1000th position and require me to fill up every space until that point.  I just want to avoid this if possible.

Comment: @canistr: You can't avoid it. The space up to that point absolutely has to be filled. It is you who'll have to fill it explicitly, or the system will fill for you implicitly. There's no way around it. There's will be no observable difference in performance between these two scenarios.

Comment: I'd like to retract my answer. Please un-accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE * f = fopen ("/tmp/x.txt", "w");

    fseek (f, 3, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite ("c", 1, 1, f);

    fseek (f, 10, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite ("j", 1, 1, f);

    fclose (f);
}
```

When this runs, the hexdump of /tmp/x.txt is

```
00 00 00 63 00 00 00 00  00 00 6a          | ...c.... ..j
```

fseek is based on lseek which is [capable of recognising "holes"](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek) in files (ranges of zeroes which haven't been written yet) but the underlying file system needs to support this.

It's not brilliantly clear to me from the manpage that the holes are strictly required to be zeroes, but that seems to be the case in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `ftello`. Then use `fwrite`.
You can also use `lseek`/`write`, if you're using fd's instead of `FILE*`s.